# Equicontinuity is not an open condition

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-dynamics, equicontinuity

I am reading the book "Arithmetic Dynamics" from Joseph Silverman that has the following comment about the Fatou set:

[image]

where the Fatou of a map means the Fatou set of its iterations. I could not find or build any example of a rational function such that the set of their points where there is equicontinuity wasn't open. Does anyone know any example or a place where it is one?

Comment: Excuse me, what does it mean for a single map to be "equicontinuous"?

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I guess it's a typo, it should be the set of iterates of $\phi$ that form an equicontinuous family

Comment: Exactly! Equicontinuity of the family $\{\phi^n}_{n \geq 0}$. where super $n$ means the iterations of $\phi$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example, which is not elementary (maybe there is something simpler).

Take $f(z)=e^{2i\pi \alpha}z +z^2$, where $\alpha=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$.
Then it is a theorem (by works of Siegel and Petersen) that there is a unique maximal Jordan domain $U$ containing $0$ such that $f: U \to U$ is holomorphically conjugated to $z \mapsto e^{2i\pi \alpha }z$, and that the boundary of $U$ is an invariant Jordan curve $\Gamma$ on which $f$ is topologically conjugated to the same rotation $z \mapsto e^{2i\pi \alpha}z$.

Then it is clear that $\{f^n \}$ is equicontinuous on $\overline{U}$, the closure of $U$. However, only $U$ is in the Fatou set, while $\Gamma$ is in the Julia set.

---

Edit

Or something much much simpler: if $z$ is a fixed point of $f$, then obviously $\{f^n\}$ is equicontinuous on $\{z\}$. However, if $z$ is a repelling fixed point, $\{f^n\}$ cannot be equicontinuous on any neighborhood of $z$.